# vscode json schema intellicode suggestions field order

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

the suggestions offered by the intellicode for JSON by default sorts all objects by name. Is there a way to display them in the same order they are defined in the schema?

Comment: I think you should maybe ask that on their GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.